# How to enable button A on button click of button B in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Abc.vue

```
     <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            <v-btn class="changeNumberBtn" disabled @click="changeNumber()">Change Number</v-btn>
          </v-flex>

<v-btn round block color="blue darken-3" dark large @click="generateCode">Continue</v-btn>
```

Currently `Change Number` button is disabled. How can I enable `Change Number` button when I click on `Continue` button ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `generateCode`? If it has some logic, just toggle some bool value to it, like:

```
generateCode() {
  this.toggleButton = true
  //rest of your logic
}

<v-btn class="changeNumberBtn" :disabled="toggleButton" @click="changeNumber()">Change Number</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally disable/enable button as below.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data: {
    disabled: true,
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button  id="name" class="form-control" :disabled="disabled">Change Number</button>
  <button @click="disabled = !disabled">Continue</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep a property in data say `numberDisabled`. Initialize it to `true` then on click of Continue, change toggle its value to false and in the changeNumber button set disabled value to this variable.

```
<v-flex xs12 sm6>
    <v-btn class="changeNumberBtn" :disabled="numberDisabled" @click="changeNumber()">Change Number</v-btn>
</v-flex>

<v-btn round block color="blue darken-3" dark large @click="numberDisabled=false;">Continue</v-btn>
```

just to show the idea, I am changing the variable on `@click`, though you can move it inside `generateCode` method.